# Require correct dependency to setup birt in springboot project

Tags: pom.xml, birt

My objective is to integrate Birt Reports into my springboot project.I tried using the below dependency in pom.xml . Inside the pom.xml file there is no error. But in my project , only after I copy paste this dependency i am getting an error. What is the correct birt report depenedency required to intergrate birt reports to springboot project

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.innoventsolutions.birt.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.8.0-20180626</artifactId>
         <version>4.8.0</version>
      </dependency>
```